# Grabbing an image from a page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hyperlink

So basically what I want to do is grab links to images within a page and convert them to images. Right now, I have code that will grab any link within a post on the forums and converts them to images, but I want it more specific than that. I want to be able to grab images using the main 4 web image extensions (.jpg, .gif, .png, .bmp). I'm new to jQuery so I'd really love some help on this. Here's my code that I have so far:

```
(function($) {
    if ($('#nav a[href*="/forum/3828932/"]').length && location.href.indexOf('/1/') !== -1) {
        $('td.c_post:eq(0) a').each(function () {
            link = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).html('<a href="' + link + '"><img src="' + link + '" alt="Icon" /></a>')
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the `ends-with` selector to select anchor with href ends with those values
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

and multiple selector
http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

so your selector may look something like

```
$('td.c_post:eq(0) a[href$=".jpg"],td.c_post:eq(0) a[href$=".png"],td.c_post:eq(0) a[href$=".gif"],td.c_post:eq(0) a[href$=".bmp"]')
```

Comment: Well, the point is not a certain instance. This will take the links to images from a post on a forum-set and have it actually display the image. I just want to limit it to what kind of link it grabs, as opposed to grabbing every link from the post.

Comment: I understood. But what I want to confirm is if your other selectors `$('#nav a[href*="/forum/3828932/"]')` and `$('td.c_post:eq(0))` are valid.

Comment: Got it figured. Friend helped me out.